# Individual P-values in Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic-regression, multicollinearity

I ran a logistic regression with like 10 variables (with R) and some of them have high P-values (>0.05). Should we follow the elimination techniques that we follow in multiple linear regression to remove insignificant variables? Or is the method different in logistic regression?

I'm new to this field so please pardon me if this question sounds silly.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have more luck asking this question in the data sciences site:  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Augusto. I just posted it.

Comment: Moved question to data science exchange.